# weird error in IE in central error page using jsp:include J2EE app

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, jakarta-ee, error-handling

I dont have exact words how to explain this error in IE but will try best...here goes.

I've following in web.xml

```
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpages/Error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

So whenever that exception happens in the application, we go to `/errorpages/Error.jsp` 
Error.jsp is getting the error messages using following attributes and simply puts them in a textarea (they are converted to `strings` later)

```
codeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
messageObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message");
typeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type");
```

However, `Error.jsp` page also has `<jsp:include>` to display the left navigation menu.

```
<jsp:include page="/common/header.jsp" flush="true">
     <jsp:param name="path" value="images"/>
</jsp:include>
```

having the `jsp:include` results in page not being displayed in IE ...thought it works in Chrome.

I am stumped as to why/how this could be happening. I am using IE7.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

wow.

removing `flush="true"` works!!